Column Formatting based upon a Group - Even if there is no data in the group
I have report that has formatting on the column in a matrix.  I want to column for Total Gross sales to be light grey (=iif(Fields!STATS_GROUP.Value="GROSS", "LightGrey", "Transparent"))  but if there is no data in that column it leaves it white.  If I switch the expression.  Is there a way to do this in report builder?
enter image description here
The column that I am using is a total of the Group Stats Group
enter image description here
Is there a way to do this?
I used the formula =iif(Fields!STATS_GROUP.Value="GROSS", "LightGrey", "Transparent")  it works fine if there is data but if there is no data it will display white.  I also try switching it to
=iif(Fields!STATS_GROUP.Value="CNC_ADJ", "Transparent", "LightGrey") but then I get the same issue on the CNC_ADJ column.
Is there a way to do this?
